# AS3 alternatives to *_exclude.xml files, loading class definitions dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, mxmlc, compc

I've been banging my head against a wall for this for almost a couple days now and hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Working in a *very* large Flash application, previously in AS2/CS3 I would have a setup like the following:

```
root.swf
-- modules
---- code_a.swf
---- code_b.swf
-- views
---- view_a.swf
---- view_b.swf
```

Using `_exclude.xml` files, I could exclude the classes defined in `code_a` and `code_b` from the ouptut .swf of `view_a` and `view_b`. `root.swf` would be responsible for loading the code modules before `view_a` or `view_b`, ensuring that class definitions that `view_a` and `view_b` depended on existed.

**The Problem**

We've recently migrated to using Actionscript 3/CS5. `*_exclude.xml` files no longer exist. To get the same functionality as above, I've tried the following:

My setup now looks something like:

```
root.swf
-- modules
---- class_a.as
---- class_b.as
-- views
---- view_a.swf
---- view_b.swf
```

Use `mxmlc` to compile `root.swf`, `view_a.swf` and `view_b.swf`, passing it `-externs` option to specify classes that will be loaded externally (the two classes in `modules`). This ensures that the class is excluded from the compiled swf.

Use `compc` to compile `class_a.as` and `class_b.as` into `classes.swf`, using `-directory=true` to access `library.swf` for external loading.

However, when I try running one of the two view files which depend on `classes.swf`, I get runtime errors telling me that a class definition is not present.

**Current Workaround**

I've devised a workaround which I'm currently not happy with as it's backwards to the modular approach that I was previously using:

Rather than loading the code modules, I statically link all class definitions required by child movies into `root.swf`. When building `root.swf`, I use the `-link-report` option of `mxmlc` to provide a list of included classes. When building child swfs, I can the use `-load-externs` to ensure that class definitions that already exist will not be included in the compile output.

Is there a way that anyone is aware of to replicate the AS2/_exclude.xml solution that I had using AS3/CS5?

Comment: Is this command line mxmlc, Flash Builder, or Flash Pro?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend compiling shared libraries to SWCs.

There are other options such as RSLs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f1e

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm looking into using RSLs. The problem I'm running into now is that the class definition is still compiled into my main container swf when publishing from Flash CS5, even after marking the libraries as external or RSL.. I can use command line compilers to achieve the results that I'm after, but I need to figure out a way to support this from within the Flash IDE as well.. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this Flash Pro or Flash Builder?  Your SWF should compile only assembly that needs to be linked.  Are you sure there's no reference to that class definition in your main container?

Comment: Using Flash Pro. I've set a reference to an external swc and have set it as "external" which, according to Adobe docs, should exclude any class definitions (even if referenced in the container) from the container. Problem is, it's not working - it's *really* starting to seem like a Flash Pro bug as it works fine from command line.

Comment: Clearly you've hosted any external references as well, of course?  (external linkage deployed to your environment).  Everything has been preloaded?  Is there an exception generated at runtime?  Probably 'Class ... not found'.  [This post](http://www.wannaknowflex.com/2010/05/flex-linkage-difference-between-rsl-and-external/) has been mentioned here regarding linkage.